# discord js messageCollector giving out empty content

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a ticket system with my bot. It first sends an embed with a bit of information and 4 buttons attached. When pressing a button the bot should send a message to which the user should respond. It works when using the response feature of discord. But is there a way to get the content of a single message which is not a direct response the the bots message?

```
const messageCollector = ticketChannel.createMessageCollector()
                    
messageCollector.on('collect', m => {
console.log(m)
 answered = true;
})
```

Comment: Have you enabled the message content intent on the developer portal and on the client initialization?

Comment: yeah i enabled it already and have `GuildMessages` as an intent. That should be all right? I mean it works when responding to the message of the bot but it wont work with an independent message but thats the way it should work

Comment: i forgot the `MessageContent` intent. Its fixed now, thanks xd